# Conversion from code point to UTF-16 code unit surrogate pair

Tags: unicode, utf-16

I am attempting to convert a Unicode character to a UTF-16 surrogate pair:

The character "Face with Medical Mask"  is code point `U+1F637`.

In binary this is: `1 1111 0110 0011 0111`.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) to encode this to UTF-16 I need to do the following:

1. 0x10000 is subtracted from the code point

   `11111011000110111 - 10000 = 011111011000100111`
2. The high ten bits (in the range 0x000–0x3FF) are added to 0xD800 to give the first 16-bit code unit or high surrogate (W1)

   `0001111101  + 1101100000000000 = 01101100001111101 (D87D)`
3. The low ten bits (also in the range 0x000–0x3FF) are added to 0xDC00 to give the second 16-bit code unit or low surrogate (W2), which will be in the range 0xDC00–0xDFFF.

   `1000100111 + 1101110000000000 = 01101111000100111 (DE27)`

So I have two code units `D87D` and `DE27`, but I know the correct result is:

```js
console.log('\uD83D\uDE37')
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have:

```
0x10000 is subtracted from the code point 

11111011000110111 - 10000 = 011111011000100111
```

But 0x10000 is 1 0000 0000 0000 0000 in binary.  The correct arithmetic is therefore:

```
1 1111 0110 0011 0111 - 1 0000 0000 0000 0000 = 0 1111 0110 0011 0111
```

Answer (score 0):

You can subtract directly `10000` from `1f637` to have the result of `f637` in hex.